# Converse of Two-Path Test

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The "Two-Path Test" states that "if $f(x,y)$ has different limits along two different paths as $(x,y)$ approaches $(a,b)$, then $\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}f(x,y)$ does not exist." My question is, if $f(x,y)$ has the same limit along every path as $(x,y)$ approaches $(a,b)$, does $\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}f(x,y)$ exist? Here, a "path" does not have to be linear, but perhaps it is harmless to assume that it is simple (not crossing itself) and smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ approaching $(a,b)$ there is  a polygonal path through these points ending at $(a,b)$. Hence the  answer is YES.

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard to imagine (and then construct) a function which is zero everywhere but for a single point on each circle $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = 1/n^2$ for each positive integer $n.$  This type of function is likely to really stress your definition of "path" to its breaking point.  (continuous paths should work, but they can be quite bizarre compared to simple smooth paths)

What we can say in full generality is that "If for any sequences of points $(x_n, y_n)$ that converges to $(a,b),$ the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n, y_n)$ exists and is equal to $L,$ then $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (a,b)} f(x,y) = L$$